# Comparing a list of known animals to a master list of animals

Tags: python

This script works for what I need it to do, but I'm not all that proficient with Python yet, so I was wondering if any of the more seasoned python veterans would go about it differently.

```
import os
import string
import re

'''This script will take in an input list of strictly stellar IDs, and compare those IDs to a master file 
with IDs AND photometric data. It will then write to a file, the lines from the master file that correspond to the known IDs 
in the IDs list.'''

def pullIDs(file_input):
    '''Pulls Mon-IDs from input file.'''
    arrayID = []
    with open(file_input,'rU') as user_file:
        for line in user_file:
            arrayID.append(re.findall('Mon\-\d{6}',line))
    return arrayID

def pullLines(file_input):
    '''Creates an array component for each
    line in the input file.'''
    arrayLines = []
    with open(file_input,'rU') as info:
        for item in info:
            item.split
            arrayLines.append(item)
    return arrayLines

def getHeader(file_input):
    '''Assuming the file-header begins with a '#',
    this will pull the header line.'''
    with open(file_input,'rU') as title:
        for line in title:
            if line.startswith('#'):
                header = line
    return header

known_stars = raw_input("Enter your ID list: ")
master_list = raw_input("Enter your master list: ")
results_list = raw_input("Name your output file: ")

with open(results_list,"w+") as output:
    output.write(getHeader(master_list))
    for item in pullIDs(known_stars):
        for items in pullLines(master_list):
            if items[:10] in item:
                output.write(items)

output_fileSIZE = os.stat(results_list).st_size
if output_fileSIZE > 0:
    print "\nYour output file has been written to.\n"
else:
    print "\nThere was an error writing to your file.\n"
```

This essentially takes a list of known animals, say, `cat` and `dog`, and compares that list to a master list of animals and their respective information.

For example:

> ```
> cat female 2 gray playful
> dog male 9 black aggressive
> giraffe male 12 tall hungry
> elephant male 33 gray lonely
> etc.
> ```

By creating two arrays for both lists, it searches for an animal that exists in both files and, once found, prints all of the more in-depth results from the 'master list' to a file.

So my file would look like this:

> ```
> cat female 2 gray playful
> dog male 9 black aggressive
> ```

because I only had a 'known list' of cats and dogs.

I'm just looking for tips on how to make this script better.  It also prints a header for the column information.

Comment: As written I don't believe `pullLines` does what you expect. Because there is no call to the line's member `item.split`, and even if there was its return would be ignored, it appears to be equivalent to `with open(file_input,'rU') as info: return info.readlines()`

Comment: The program gives me back the info I was expecting, so I assume the `item.split` line is redundant?

Comment: Yes. `item.split` retrieves the bound split method, but does not call it. Having that code there distracts from the actual intention, making it look like perhaps you wanted `items = item.split(); arrayLines.append(items)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the sort of thing that Python is really good at.  Your code seems like it functions, but it will be very inefficient for large data sets. For each input value you have to check every line in the the master list -- and the way you have it set up here you're going to read the master list off disk for each input value as well, so it will be really slow.

The first step obvious fix is to load the master list into memory and keep it around for the duration of a session.  This is a fairly simple change to your existing code.  First, change your pull_lines so it returns a dictionary instead of a list:

```
def pullLines(file_input):
    '''returns a dictionary of the entries in <file_input> keyed by the first item in each line'''
    master_dict = {}
    with open(file_input,'rU') as info:
        for eachline in info.readlines():
            tokens = eachline.split()
            master_dict[tokens[0]] = tokens[1:]
```

Then, you move pull lines out of the inner loop:

```
lookup = pull_lines(path_to_file)
with open(results_list,"w+") as output:
    output.write(getHeader(master_list))
    for item in pullIDs(known_stars):
        if item in lookup:
            output.write(lookup[item])
```

This has a couple of advantages

1) not hitting the disk for every query will be much faster

2) the dictionary lookup faction is much faster than straight for loop comparison, since the dictionary uses hashed values instead of more expensive string compares.

As an aside, you should look into [readlines](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html), which the usual pythonic way of reading text files with info on lines.

For the longer term this is a great application for Python's built in database functionality (with the sqllite module). You could convert your existing text files into a sqllite database and then your lookups can be much more flexible and precise ('find spectrum and power for stars with id > X and < Y' sort of thing).  You probably also want to set this file up so you could call it from the command line, which would involve using the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module to grab command line arguments and out them into known_stars, master_list and output_file

Comment: I disagree with the suggestion that `for line in afile.readlines(): ...` is more pythonic than `for line in afile: ...`, but other than that I agree with this. Note also that depending on the later usage, it may make more sense to do `key, value = eachline.split(1)`

Comment: @MichaelUrman `split(1)` is a `TypeError`, you mean `split(None, 1)` instead.

Comment: @JanneKarila You're spot on. My mistake! I'd fix it if I could.

Comment: @MichaelUrman What would be the benefit of using `split(None,1)`?

Comment: @Matt It all depends on what you need in theodox's example `master_dict`. If you want the remainder of the line split similarly (mapping the key to list of items), the original code is more useful; if you want to handle the remainder of the line as a single token (mapping the key to the rest of the line) `split(None, 1)` gets you there instead.

Comment: I see. That would be ideal if I understand the point correctly. I'd never split up the columns other than `Mon-IDs` and `the rest of them`. I think I should practice with the dictionary stuff more, I haven't ventured into that python territory yet. Thanks.